# ELM327 Returning "ERROR" when sending OBD Commands

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

I am currently working on an Android Application to Read from a vehicle's OBDII Port via a ELM327 bluetooth dongle...

For those of you who dont know much about the ELM, I would reccomend this data sheet, it has been very helpful...

[Data Sheet](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf)

I am able to connect to the dongle, and I can use every "AT" command with no issues whatsoever, however when I try to issue an OBD command, say "010C"for instance, I receive and error message, at first I thought that the baud rates might be incorrect. I tried with all of the different baud rates and every time I try to issue an OBD command I receive an "ERROR" response, Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out, had to change the protocol, and also remove the particular dongle that I am using which resets the buffer. There is an AT command that you can see in the datasheet that is used to auto-detect which particular protocol that vehicle is using. This will make sure that you are using the proper protocol for whatever vehicle you are trying to get data from. If anyone needs any more information, feel free to PM me!

Comment: I have some doubts while issuing OBD commands,I have successfully able to connect with odb devices but when i am trying to send ATZ command the application gets crash, can you please help me on this,Thanks,:)

Comment: Do you have some example code? What application are you using? Have you tried using the example Bluetooth chat application?

Comment: @VRKinght:Yes I have the sample code , I did not use the Blue tooth Chat Application , I have written myself you can review that in he gist which I shared with you , I was successfully able to find the paired OBD and establish the connection with OBD, when i m trying to send ATZ Command , the problem occurs, please see the gist https://gist.github.com/sankarganesh/6376031, this gist holds the Activity file and one more gist for Bluetooth Socket Listener https://gist.github.com/sankarganesh/6376039

Comment: Did you go through my comment mate,:)

Comment: please have look on this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528792/unable-to-send-atz-command-to-elm-327-after-establishing-connection-with-elm327

Answer (score 0):

It seems your vehicle's obd interface protocol selection and connection failed. When I tried to request 010C command, I also got an error. Actually I got error with any commands. When I connected to obd properly, it solved my trouble.

To connect properly, you should follow steps which is presented into my answer:

[answered question: "Initialization of obd adapter"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29364593/2000405)