# Error running 01 46, response: ...UNABLETOCONNECT

Tags: android, bluetooth, torque, baud-rate, elm327

Getting the data from OBD II simulator to android application via Bluetooth successfully.

Now I am trying get the data from ELM327 device to android application.

I have an ELM327 device connected to my Car. Bluetooth connection happens by ECU connection fails with unable to connect error.

getting below error,
D:NetworkManagementSocketTagger: tagSocket(80) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1

E : Failed to run command. -> Error running 01 46, response: ...UNABLETOCONNECT

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this help? https://obd2-elm327.com/obd2-elm327-can-not-connect-ecu

Comment: @ukBaz , Thanks fro you reply. ELM327 is working with another application.

Answer (score 0):

i am trying to create an ionic obd-2 application for my university project. i am using "BluetoothSerial" in order to connect with obd simulator i have done all the settings required(that i know of) but i have hit a wall and i dont know what to do next. i connected to the bluetooth device and when is send the "ATZ" commands using bluetoothserial.write(obdcommand) i am getting "OK" can you please share with me how you connected with bluetoothserial or am i missing something...

I will post my code dow below.

```
    obdcommands=['ATD','ATZ','ATE0','ATL0','ATS0','ATH0','ATAT2','ATSP0','0100', '0105\r', '010C'];

   constructor(private bluetooth:BluetoothSerial,
          private DataSrv:DataSrvService,
          private action:ActionSheetController,
          private permission:AndroidPermissions, 
          private alert: AlertController,
          private toastctrl:ToastController) {
    }

connect(dvc)
{
if(dvc.address=="")
this.showError("No Address");
else{
this.bluetooth.connect(dvc.address).subscribe(success=>
  {
    this.modal.dismiss(null, 'cancel');
    this.presentToast("Connected Successfully");
    this.blue=false;
    this.deviceConnected();
    this.bluetooth.available().then(tr=>{alert(tr)})

    },error=>{
     alert("Connect Error: "+error);
    })

   }

    }
    deviceConnected()
  {
   this.bluetooth.subscribe('\n').subscribe(success=>{

    alert("Subscribed Successfully" +success);


   })

  }

 async searchOBD()
 {
  for(let k=0;k<this.obdcommands.length;k++)
    {
      await this.bluetooth.write(this.obdcommands[k]).then( (success) => {
        alert('Connected: '+this.obdcommands[k]+'Data: '+success );
    },
    (error) => {
        alert('Reading failed: ' + error );
    });

     } 
    }
```

Comment: it is long back and I don't have to remember exactly. Can you find this sample code link.https://github.com/pires/android-obd-reader